Character movement problem Gamemaker studio
I was trying to make an basic character movement, everything worked till i turn on the gravity. Since im new to gamemaker i was don't able to fix this issue by myself, if you can help please.
I tried many codes, but since gamemaker changed it syntax a bit all of them don't working, even chat gpt don't helped.

The build-in Gravity checkbox is for physics-based objects, If you turn on the Gravity, then it will follow different rules, either try implementing an own gravity system, or use the physics system instead.
